# Make Ajax Get Request when a key is typed into a search box

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am trying to create a real time search box in my Django Application. The general idea is that when a key is pressed in the search field, it should send the get request to my server, and on success, the data should append to my search-result p tag. However, for some reason, I am appending my entire HTML content. I want to only append the information sent inside the search box.

This is what I have so far.

Html

```
 <form method="get" action="{% url 'sell' %}" class="search_form center-block">
                    <!--{% csrf_token %}-->
                    <div class="input-group search_option">
                      <input type="text" id="searchBox" class="search_field form-control" name="q" placeholder="Search for...">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <input id="search" class="search_submit btn btn-default" onclick="myFunction()" type="submit" value="Search">
                        </span>
           </div><!-- /input-group -->
</form>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $('.search_field').keyup(function(){
              $.ajax({
                  url: "{% url 'sell' %}",
                  type: "GET",
                  cache: false,
                  data: { 'search_text' : $('.search_field').val() },
                  success: function(data){
                    $('#search-results').append(data);
                  }
              });
          });
        });
```

I believe data is where I am trying to get the value off of the search_field input, but for some reason. This isn't working.

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: >  However, for some reason, I am appending my entire HTML content. I want to only append the information sent inside the search box.


Do you mean that you are SENDING too much or appending too much upon receipt of a response? If the latter, what does the response look like? If the server is replying with html then you may want to change it to reply with JSON, or else parse the HTML to only find the content you want.

(edit: sorry, the formatting on this is a bit of a mess! Hopefully my question/comment makes sense.)

Comment: It is sending too much. Yes, i want to parse the HTML to only find the content that I want, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: If you are able to provide us with an example response that would help. You will likely need to do something like  $('#search-results').append($(data).find("body").text());

Comment: So, I have a search box where you can type characters in. Every time a key is pressed, I want the response to be the character that was typed by the user

Answer (score 0):

what about just:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

```
      $('.search_field').keyup(function(){
          var data = $('.search_field').val(); 
          $.ajax({
              url: "{% url 'sell' %}",
              type: "GET",
              cache: false,
              data: data,
              success: function(data){
                $('#search-results').append(data);
              }
          });
      });
    });
```

```

Comment: Doesn't work, it gives me (index):132 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined(…)

Comment: @J_LIU I'm so confused. I have no idea why I was continuing the conversation with you on somebody else's answer. Was it their solution that worked, or mine above?

Comment: Please clarify what you tried, and what the results were.

Comment: success: function(data){
                    $("p").append($(data).find(".search_field").text());
                    alert();
} I added this to my succes, and its giving me the response as ?search_text=<whatever I typed into search box>, which is what i want. However, it is appending it to my #search_results area

Comment: I don't see the <p> tag in your html above. Why don't you give it a class name so you can target it more specifically?  Such as: <p class='server-result'></p>

Comment: And if that function is working for you, change it to function(data){ $(".server-result").append($(data).find(".search_field").text()); alert(); }

 And you probably will need to change that 'append' to 'text', so it doesn't just keep creating a longer and longer string.

Comment: Well, i tried everything that you suggested, and it still doesn't work

Comment: moved to chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126987/discussion-between-lexjacobs-and-j-liu

Answer (score 0):

```
data: { 'search_text' : $('#searchBox').val() },
```

Comment: So that worked, and its getting the correct response, but I can't seem to retrieve the data on success. Any idea?

Comment: Take a look at the object that is returned to the success call back. You probably need to specify a key within that object.
```   
 success: function(data){
                    console.log('data', data);
                    $('#search-results').append(data);
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $('.search_field').keyup(function(event){
              $.ajax({
                  url: "{% url 'sell' %}",
                  type: "GET",
                  cache: false,
                  data: { 'search_text' : event.target.value },
                  success: function(data){
                    $('#search-results').append(data);
                  }
              });
          });
        });
```

Comment: This doesn't work either, it is still appending the entire HTML content to search results

Comment: Maybe you have this entire HTML in your response ?

Comment: event.target.value will give you your input filed value, 
$('#search-results').append(data); in this place you put everything you get from the server.
Can you show the response from the server ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use id #searchBox instead of class. for the URL, you should type it out, for example "/items"
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could try using select2 control for your search box
https://select2.github.io/

using CDN reference

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

html:

```
<select id="searchBox"></select>
```

js:

```
$("#searchBox").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: "{% url 'sell' %}",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        delay: 250,
        method: "GET",
        data: function (params) {
          return {
            q: params.term, // search term
            page: params.page
          };
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
            // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
            // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
            // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
            // scrolling can be used
            //params.page = params.page || 1;
            params.page = params.page || 1;

              return {
                results: data.items,
                pagination: {
                  more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
                }
              };
            },
            cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    templateResult: function (data) { return data.text; }, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
    templateSelection: function (data, container) { return data.text; } // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery autocomplete instead with ajax.
[Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

```
    $("#searchBox").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
       $.ajax({
           url: "your action",
           type: "GET",
           data: request,
           success: function (data) {
             response($.map(data.listName, function (element,index) { // return a list of map
               return {
                     label: element.Name, // dropdown text
                     value: element.Value,// dropdown value
                     id   : element.nameId // you can declare n number of variable based on your need

                 };
             });
         }
     });
   },
   select: function (event, ui) {
    // you can set the value other element if needed
    var value= ui.item.value;
    var id = ui.item.id;       
}
```

});

you can also set other option delay,minLength etc,

Comment: Can you please give me an example of how autocomplete can be used in this instance. I tried using it, but it didn't quite work out for me.